# Converting a string (with scientific notation) to an int in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a set of strings from a txt file into int's within a list. I was able to find a nice snippet of code that returns each line and then I proceeded to try and convert it to an int. The problem is that the numbers are in scientific notation and I get this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.404788e-001'.

This is the code I've been messing around with

```
data = []
rawText = open ("data.txt","r")

for line in rawText.readlines():
    for i in line.split():
        data.append(int(i))

print data[1]
rawText.close()
```

Comment: They aren't just "in scientific notation"; they represent non-integers. Exactly what result were you hoping to get for the input '3.404788e-001'?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `float(i)` or `decimal.Decimal(i)` for floating point numbers, depending on how important maintaining precision is to you.
`float` will store the numbers in machine-precision IEEE floating point, while `Decimal` will maintain full accuracy, at the cost of being slower.
Also, you can iterate over an open file, you don't need to use `readlines()`.
And a single list comprehension can do everything you need:

```
data = [float(number)
        for line in open('data.txt', 'r')
        for number in line.split()]
```

If you really only need integers, you can use `int(float(number))`

Answer (score 5):

Your string looks like a `float`, so convert it to a `float` first.