# Need to convert 4.2215E+01 type scientific number format to float in Python

Tags: python, valueconverter

I am extracting data from an excel file which is saved by a scientific software in the following way:
4.2215E+01 which I need to be saved as 42.215.

I can figure out a way to write to code which does that. What I need to know is if python already provides a way to do that which would make me needing to write another code for it unnecessary.

I am a very new to python do excuse me if the answer is obvious.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338507/converting-a-string-with-scientific-notation-to-an-int-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the string to float() like this:

```
n = float("4.2215E+01")
print n
> 42.215
```