# how to convert 3.9055320000e+06 this type of number to interger in python?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, machine-learning

I have XML files containing this type of numbers values 3.9055320000e+06 and while storing it in list, it stores like u'3.9055320000e+06' so, how can i convert this to integer. As i want to use it in machine learning algorithms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a string (with scientific notation) to an int in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338507/converting-a-string-with-scientific-notation-to-an-int-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert it to `float`, and then to `int`:

```
>>> float(u'3.9055320000e+06')
3905532.0
>>> int(float(u'3.9055320000e+06'))
3905532
>>>
```