# How to determine the numeric type of String values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading numeric data from a database that it was by default inserted as a string and I am applying a rule to process out these numbers but it fails when the encountered value is something like `-1.03432e+006` or `-1.03426e+006`, that is,

```
id    transferred speed values
---   ------------------------
 0     4
 1     3
 2     9
 3     2
 4    -1.03432e+006
 5    -1.03427e+006
 6    -1.03426e+006
 7
 8     12

def process_out_transferred_speed(value):
    passed_values = []
    failed_values = []
    if value!= None or value!= " ":
        if int(value) < 0 or int(value) > 48:
            passed_values.append(value)
        else:
            failed_values.append(value)
```

When the value `-1.03432e+006` is read by the first condition, the `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-1.03432e+006'` problem arises and this is reasonable since value is `string` and it gets converted to an `int` but this is not possible for `-1.03432e+006` because `int` does not support this value.

My question is: how can I determine the type of value from this `string` so I can insert a rule to avoid this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338507/converting-a-string-with-scientific-notation-to-an-int-in-python

Comment: You can use `float(value)` to parse.

Comment: `int(float('-1.03432e+006'))`.

Comment: But what if I just want to read int values and avoid the floats? How can I do this?

Comment: You're also going to have a problem with that empty / blank string on line 7.

Comment: @PM2Ring for that problem I use `value!=" "` so I can avoid blank entries.

Comment: -1.03432e+006 == -1034320.0, so it can be considered an integer. So why do you want to exclude it? It passes your `value < 0 or value > 48` test.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes but this is a hard coded way and I would have to exclude `-1.03432e+006` , `-1.03426e+006` and `-1.03432e+006`, but what if later on a different number such as `-1.03420e+006` arises? I will have to add this number to the code and this is not a solution I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pythonic way would be to just try it and catch the exception.

```
try:
    int(value)
    passed_values.append(value)
except ValueError:
    failed_values.append(value)
```